# How to get the div display property in c#.net before i changed div property in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

i Have one div in my default web page . The div style display none, that time in page load event i have to get the status none, but the div status changed in javascript function based on dropdown selection that i dosenot get the none status always show "" status, my code is

aspx page

```
 <div id="Div1" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" style="display: none;">
```

pageload event

```
     string Display1 = "";
    Display1 = Div1.Style["display"]; (working fine)( get the display1 value=none)
```

when i button click show the div like that in c# code

```
    Div1.Style.Add("display", "");(now show the div it is correct)
```

Dropdown Changed fire  javascript function code

```
    document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'none'; (after change dropdown Hide the div after pageload i got Display1 value="")
```

After changed javascript function i doenot get the none status in page load

Comment: what you exact wont ? you wont to show or hide your div plz reply .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like this it's below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#lnkCompany").click(function () {
                if ($("#dvClientReg").css('display') == 'block') {
                    $("#dvClientReg").css('display', 'none');
                }
                if ($("#dvCompanyReg").css('display') == 'none') {
                    $("#dvCompanyReg").css('display', 'block');

                }
            });

  });
</script>
```

i think this will help you

Comment: First you set display : 'none' your div and you don't need to do anything in your page lode event . and when you click on button then you show and hide your div like this

Answer (score 1):

DIV is a HTMLGenericalControl in ASP.Net and any changes you make it in the client to its style or attributes, i dont think it will be posted back to server, instead you can track the changes on a Hidden control which has runat server attribute to true and capture the changes.

let me know if it helps